# Ubuntu does not turn (purple screen)

Tags: boot

Changed "Secure Boot" and installed ubuntu

At startup, a purple screen, changing "Secure Boot" and the system is switched

"nomodeset" does not eliminate the purple screen

Install the drivers for the video card:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

...changing "Secure Boot" and i see on a black screen cursor to a crosshair

If not change "Secure Boot" will be purple screen

Comment: "nomodeset" does not eliminate the purple screen

Comment: If those answers from the above link do not fully address your question, please ask a new question, refer to the prior answer and specify why it does not work for you so we may look into it further.